# Administrative activity under wrong admin user

Tags: contacts, admin, activity

I'm having a very strange (I think problem). I am logged in to the back end of my Joomla site with my superuser credentials. Several months ago I set up a test contact "Ritson The Dog" with the email as ritson@heritagemuse.com (He's a very talented puppy but has trouble with the opposable thumb thing).

Now, every administrative activity within CiviCRM shows Ritson The Dog as the Source Contact name. I looked through the forums and haven't been able to find where the default "Source" is set, but I think that may be the problem. Any thoughts?

Is there a way to batch change each contact activity record so that the source contact can be me and not my dog?
Thanks,
Kate

Answer (score 1):

Usually the source is the logged in user. Are you by any way logged in as Ritson?  Or did you accendentially overwrite your own civicrm profile?

Comment: No - my profile and Ritson's are both there and are totally different. I sometimes login as Ritson when I'm testing functionality, bouncing back and forth between the site view and the administrator view. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes that could be the issue. Because everything you do as Ritson will contain Ritson as source

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't mind losing any Ritson-specific activity, you should be able to merge the two records - this will change the 'source contact' to your record.

Change Ritson's email to match your own. You can use the Contacts > Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts to match them, but it's simpler to just search for your email - you can select the two records on the search results list and then select 'Merge Contacts' from the action list.

On the Merge Contacts page, make sure that your record is the original, and Ritson's is the duplicate (if they aren't, click on 'Flip between original and duplicate contacts').

Make sure the contact information is **not** selected (as this will overwrite your record), and then select 'Move related... Activities'.

(You can move the other related data as well, but be aware that if the records have memberships of the same type, they will also overwrite your existing membership - there is an option to create a 'new' membership that will ensure both are kept)